# Developing atom packages in typescript

Tags: typescript, package, atom-editor

I was wondering if anybody has done this successfully?  I couldn't find any support for this.

Some references to documentation or existing  code would be appreciated.

I'm aware that atom runs on node and that nodes has a typescript compiler package.

I'm specifically wondering if there were typescript  definition files for the modules required to build atom packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately typescript will compile to Javascript so anything that can be written in JS can be written in TS, atom packages included.

As far as typings go, DefinitelyTyped is the most common repository for such files. I believe this is the typing you're looking for:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/atom/atom.d.ts

You can save and include that manually if you like but the recommended approach is to use a typings manager like [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)  or [TSD (deprecated)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd). TSD is deprecated in favor of typings, but has a simpler interface so I wouldn't call it evil to use it as a learning experience.

In case you're interested in a real world example, it looks like the [atom-typescript](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript) plugin is written in typescript (at least partially), though that may be too big to be easily understood.

Comment: Note: This answer is rather old. Please use the @types namespace on NPM for current projects.